# Visualize Layers of Convolution in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, imshow

I have this code for convolutional neural network.

```
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS], name='input')
convnet1 = conv_2d(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet1 = max_pool_2d(convnet1, FILTER_SIZE)
convnet2 = conv_2d(convnet1, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL*2, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet2 = max_pool_2d(convnet2, FILTER_SIZE)
convnet_final = fully_connected(convnet2, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL*16, activation='relu')
convnet_final = dropout(convnet_final, 0.8)
convnet_final = fully_connected(convnet_final, NUM_OUTPUT, activation='softmax')
convnet_final = regression(convnet_final, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet_final, tensorboard_dir='log')
```

How can I visualize convnet1 or convnet2? I have this code already:

```
img = convnet1[0, :, :,  0]
```

But the data type of **img** is **Tensor("MaxPool2D/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 52, 52, 32), dtype=float32)**. I still need it to convert to something like numpy array or something that I will be able to pass in **imshow()** or any other image display. I can also get the session in which this model is running by using **model.session**.

Comment: I would of used opencv library's imshow() here. You can create a single or multi-image map of your numpy arrays easily with it. You can use even colour mapping, if it suit to your purposes. You have to choose which two dimensions you want to visualize in e.g. grayscale format and match imshow array size to fit to image you are showing. Looks similar in matplotlib, though few more lines of code is needed vs. opencv. https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-demo-py

Comment: Hi Mika72, that's what's I'm having difficulty with. I want to create a numpy array from Tensor("MaxPool2D/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 52, 52, 32), dtype=float32).

Comment: Using img = convnet1[0, :, :,  0] so, that x and y coordinates are having ':', to be removed dimensions are having '0' and value field is also having ':' should do?